# import Active Directory into User Profiles in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Could anyone guide me how to import Active Directory in to user profiles in Sharepoint 2007.

I need to hide domain name when some one logs in to the site.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to access: Central Administration > Shared Services Administration > User Profiles and Properties

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827754